# Why does linking materials between objects seem to have no effect?

Tags: materials

1. I used 3 cubes.
2. I changed the first cube's material (check pic).
3. I selected the first two, then the last. I clicked the cube, pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and chose 'Material'.

I got in right menu Material.004 and Material.006 but color does not change.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It has 'changed the color' ... to Material.04.

You could have been linking materials between objects with completely different topologies.. the editor has no way of knowing which materials to assign to which faces. So by default, it will assign the material in transferred-slot-0 to all faces.

If you switch the order of the material slots in the first cube, (using the up/down arrows at the bottom right of the list,) when you link the materials to the other cubes, they will turn blue. All over.

Comment: yes I have checked. If I changed material index in 0, works but changed my cube in blue all over. Is possible to change only what I have selected? In my case only one first side. Any solution for this?

Comment: Solution:
I need copy paste to another material and select what I need to change. Then very important is the same name, like Material020, must be all on cube material Material020, other way in my case will not work. if you have better solution let me know.